# environment not behaving as expected after using transformEnvir in RevoScaleR function

Tags: r, revolution-r, microsoft-r

I have a function where I'm reading an xdf file using rxXdfToDataFrame and using a variable in my expression for rowSelection.  If I don't pass `transformEnvir=environment()`, the variable is not found.  My problem is that after calling the function with `transformEnvir`, I can't seem to reliably access `.GlobalEnv`. If I hardcode a number into `rowSelection` I don't need to use `transformEnvir` and everything works correctly. I tried setting the environment, but I'm not sure I was even doing it correctly.

The following code reproduces my problem:

```
envirtest = function()
{
   require(data.table)
   df = data.frame(x=1:10)
   selectnum = 5
   rxDataFrameToXdf(df, "testxdf.xdf")
   testdf = rxXdfToDataFrame("testxdf.xdf",rowSelection=(x==selectnum),transformEnvir=environment())
   testdt = setDT(testdf)
}
```

The error that occurs:

```
Error in envirtest() : could not find function "setDT"
```

However, if instead of `setDT()`, `data.table::setDT()` is used, then the function executes.

**edit:** I forgot to mention that I had tried it without `transformEnvir` set and everything worked properly.  Also, tables() was changed to setDT() to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: can you try with `require(data.table)` outside the function call

Comment: It doesn't change anything.  Also, objects inside the workspace are not found.

Comment: see if you can access the workspace objects using `get('object_name')`

Comment: Ah, so `get('object_name')` doesn't work, but I just found out that `get('object_name', envir=globalenv())` works.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your xdf functions.  The same behaviour occurs when you remove all RevoScaleR functions.  I can't work on this now, but will take a look again tomorrow morning.

Comment: I have tried it without `transformEnvir` and there is no error, whereas with `transformEnvir` there's an error.  tables() was probably a poor choice for an example as it leads to an object not being found, but I was trying to demonstrate that the function wasn't being found.

Comment: You are correct.  I have traced the problem and posted an answer.  I will also contact our support team with this information, so at the very least we have better information in the manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem, together with a partial explanation:

- At the completion of the transformation, the transformation environment gets cleared.
- This means it is safer to create an environment and then adding any objects into this environment before starting the rx-function.

Concretely:

```
env <- new.env()
env$selectnum = 5
```

Set up your function like this:

```
envirtest = function()
{
  require(data.table)
  df = data.frame(x=1:10)
  env <- new.env()
  env$selectnum = 5

  rxDataFrameToXdf(df, "testxdf.xdf", overwrite=TRUE)
  testdf <- rxXdfToDataFrame("testxdf.xdf",
                             rowSelection=(x==selectnum),
                             transformEnvir=env
  )
  setDT(testdf)
}
```

Now try it:

```
x <- envirtest()

Rows Read: 10, Total Rows Processed: 10, Total Chunk Time: 0.006 seconds 
Rows Processed: 1
Time to read data file: 0.00 secs.
Time to convert to data frame: less than .001 secs.

str(x)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int 5
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```